# Remove a href from php

Tags: php, href

On my website the following php code displaying a list of items but i would like to remove the hyperlink from each list item.

Could someone please help me with this?

```
<?php
        foreach($features_item as $fet_item){
            echo '<li><a href="'.get_term_link($fet_item->slug, 'feature').'">'.$fet_item->name.'</a></li>';
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: Why do you want to remove it? And what is your goal, just to have a list of items without a link?

Comment: exactly that. I don't want each item to be clickable.

Comment: So.... remove it then. This is HTML 101. However, what do you mean by not each item, only certain ones? You need to be specific.

Comment: You have to remove the `a` tag: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp Try it, maybe you can solve it by yourself! Otherwise if you get stuck just show what you have tried

Answer (score 0):

This will do it:

```
<?php
    foreach($features_item as $fet_item){
        echo '<li>'.$fet_item->name.'</li>';
    }
?>
```